# Ubuntu freezes when I try install it

Tags: freeze, 21.10

I am having problems installing Ubuntu 21.10 and not for the first time. I created a bootable USB with Rufus. My problem is when I get to the second step where you can set the Wi-Fi, the cursor is unstable.

Here is the image on the installation, **see the cursor!**

[image: the image on the installation, see the cursor!]

In my previous attempts I remember I had to enter to the GRUB Console and change something.

Comment: Sounds like it could be an issue with the installer. Or are you trying to install Ubuntu on the same external drive as the installer? I think you should try re-creating the installation stick, at any rate.

Comment: No, im trying to install Ubuntu on my new SSD.